# Determine velocity & vector of particle

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

> A particle is moving with constant velocity along a straight line
> through space. It starts at $(8, 5, 10)$ when the time $t = 0$. It is
> at $(2, 9, 5)$ when $t = 1$. The measurement units are meters, and the
> time is in measured in seconds.

I need to determine the velocity vector of the particle and the velocity. How do I go about figuring this out? I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670188/how-to-find-the-direction-of-a-particle-moving-in-space) topic which I think puts me on the right path but I'm not completely sure.

What do I do to find the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Velocity in three dimensions is just the same as velocity in 1 dimention, just everything becomes a vector, $\vec{v}= \frac{d}{dt}\vec{s} =\frac{\vec{s_2} -\vec{s_1}}{\Delta t}$

That should be easy enough to solve. And if you are interested in the magnitude of velocity, well then same as any other vector: $|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}}$